# Prevent hibernate from assuming it is updating parent when updating its child?

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate

I have a scenario where am trying to update only the child, but hibernate says updating the parent first then the child follow while in real sense I have set update to false on the parent.

the parent

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "product_bundles")
@EqualsAndHashCode(onlyExplicitlyIncluded = true)
@TypeDefs({@TypeDef(name = "json", typeClass = JsonType.class)})
public class ProductBundleEntity extends BaseEntity {

  @JsonIgnore
  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "productBundle")
  private List<ItemPriceEntity> itemPrices;
}
```

the child

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "item_prices")
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(onlyExplicitlyIncluded = true)
@TypeDefs({@TypeDef(name = "json", typeClass = JsonType.class)})
public class ItemPriceEntity extends BaseEntity {

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(
      name = "item_code",
      referencedColumnName = "product_bundle_code",
      insertable = false,
      updatable = false)
  private ProductBundleEntity productBundle;
}
```

the controller

```
public void handleCatalogReport(String catalogPayload) {
  try {
    ErpCatalogList catalogItems = getMapper().readValue(catalogPayload, ErpCatalogList.class);
    log.info("Catalog report event data received: \n" + catalogPayload);
    if (ObjectUtils.isEmpty(catalogItems.getData())) {
    } else {
      var savedRecords = itemPriceService.processCatalogPayload(catalogItems);
    }
  } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

the update function

```
public ResponseWrapper processCatalogPayload(ErpCatalogList catalogItems) {
  List<ItemPriceEntity> updateItemPrices = new ArrayList<>();
  catalogItems.getData().forEach(territoryData -> {
    territoryData.getData().forEach(catalogItem -> {
      // Check if item exists. If so update
      var itemPrice = itemPriceRepository.findByItemCodeAndTerritory(catalogItem.getItemCode(), catalogItem.getTerritory());
      if (itemPrice.isPresent()) {
        itemPrice.get().setStock(catalogItem.getActualQty());
        itemPrice.get().setProjectedStock((catalogItem.getProjectedQty() == null) ? 0 : catalogItem.getProjectedQty());
        itemPrice.get().setLastModifiedDate(Instant.now());
        updateItemPrices.add(itemPrice.get());
      }
    });
  });

  if (!updateItemPrices.isEmpty()) {
    var updatedItems = itemPriceRepository.saveAll(updateItemPrices);
    log.info("Updated itemm prices: {} ", updatedItems);
    return ResponseWrapper.builder()
            .code(HttpStatus.OK.value())
            .message("Item prices updated successfully")
            .build();
  }
  return ResponseWrapper.builder()
          .code(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND.value())
          .message("No Item prices found to update")
          .build();
}
```

the sample sql logs

```
Hibernate: select productbun0_.id as id1_10_0_, productbun0_.active as active2_10_0_, productbun0_.creation_date as creation3_10_0_, productbun0_.last_modified_date as last_mod4_10_0_, productbun0_.display_item_group as display_5_10_0_, productbun0_.image as image6_10_0_, productbun0_.items as items7_10_0_, productbun0_.price_list_set as price_li8_10_0_, productbun0_.product_bundle_code as product_9_10_0_, productbun0_.product_bundle_description as product10_10_0_, productbun0_.product_bundle_group as product11_10_0_, productbun0_.promo_bundle as promo_b12_10_0_ from product_bundles productbun0_ where productbun0_.product_bundle_code=?
Hibernate: update product_bundles set active=?, last_modified_date=?, display_item_group=?, image=?, items=?, price_list_set=?, product_bundle_code=?, product_bundle_description=?, product_bundle_group=?, promo_bundle=? where id=?
Hibernate: update product_bundles set active=?, last_modified_date=?, display_item_group=?, image=?, items=?, price_list_set=?, product_bundle_code=?, product_bundle_description=?, product_bundle_group=?, promo_bundle=? where id=?
Hibernate: update product_bundles set active=?, last_modified_date=?, display_item_group=?, image=?, items=?, price_list_set=?, product_bundle_code=?, product_bundle_description=?, product_bundle_group=?, promo_bundle=? where id=?
Hibernate: update item_prices set active=?, last_modified_date=?, currency=?, discount_price=?, display_name=?, item_code=?, product_bundle_group=?, projected_stock=?, selling_price=?, stock=?, territory=?, territory_status=?, uom=?, warehouse=? where id=?
```

[the full logs](https://pastebin.com/iEQjrZcG)

From the log it says updating `product_bundles` but in real sense hibernate is not updating the parent, it should only update the child which is `item_prices`.

What am I doing wrong,  I need to update only the `item_prices` and prevent hibernate from assuming it is also updating  `product_bundles` . Any help to what am doing wrong is very much appreciated

Comment: `updatable = false` does not what you think it does. What you want is `cascade = {}` instead

Comment: Hi @XtremeBaumer where should I use `cascade={ }`, thank you for your input